# Android: content view not yet created when using listview in fragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have fragment with two tabs, Each tab has it's respective fragment. each tab has its own list which is load from server. but my apps encountered exception like

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oj.bs/com.oj.bs.ProjectFragActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

I can't understand where is the problem. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Following is my fragment class

```
public class ResidentialFragActivity extends SherlockListFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener{

ListView listview;
ListView resListviewId;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.residential_list);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle saved) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.residential_list,container, false);
    resListviewId = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.resProjListView);
    projectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    new LoadProjects().execute();

    ListView listview = getListView();
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent href = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), ProjectDetailActivity.class);

                    String proj_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.projectId)).getText().toString();  
                        href.putExtra("proj_id", proj_id);     
            getSherlockActivity().startActivity(href);
        }
    });
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return view;
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.add(android.R.id.content,this,"residential");
    ft.attach(this);
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.detach(this);
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

//inner class for network operation
private class LoadProjects extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ..........
        //get data from the latest server
        String jsonpProjList = ResdProj.makeHttpReqToSrvr(projectUrl, "POST", projRes);

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter projAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                        projectList, R.layout.residential_list_item, 
                        new String[] {PROJ_ID,PROJ_NAME}, new int[] 
                            {R.id.projectId,R.id.projectName});
                //updating the UI
                setListAdapter(projAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: check my answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I can see lots of 'bad things' in your code. The first thing which I would never do and I'm not really sure that it will work is `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.residential_list);` . You can add `Fragments` to FragmentActivity using xml or adding directly to a `FrameLayout`. Just check the example in Android for `Fragments` for best practice how to achieve this [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) .

Second thing, no need to use this `runOnUiThread` in `onPostExecute()`, because it is running on UI thread already.

And last thing which I can think of first set content to your `FragmentActivity`, add your tabs to `ActionBar` and attach your Fragments on first / second tab. And after that you can properly populate your `ListView`'s with data using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I am agree with your first two thing but i am already added tabs from another class,when click on first tab ResidentialFragActivity class load.

Comment: You are adding FragmentActivity as tab content?

Comment: yes my another class extend SherlockFragmentActivity from that class for e.g. Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new ResidentialFragActivity()).setIcon(R.drawable.residential);
actionBar.addTab(tab);

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem ,but not sure.

```
 new LoadProjects().execute();
```

you are calling this before `listview` creating that's why there is no `view` so call after `listview` creation.

**update:-**

or call  `new LoadProjects().execute();` inside the

```
`onResume()`.it will get called after `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to remember you live in a crazy world where you can create the view for your Fragment, and it's detached from the Activity that contains it, so your although your fragment's view is ready it's not on screen and your "Content view not yet created".

You are going to want to implement `onActivityCreated` on your Fragment and call

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    new LoadProjects().execute();
}
```

from there.

That will ensure that both your fragment and activity are created.  BUT WAIT there's more.  Also remember that you can leave your activity with a `activity.startActivity(...)`, and your fragment may still be around (maybe detached maybe gone).  In that case the `onActivityCreated` will get called again when your activity resumes and your fragment is reattached.  So that might get called more often than you want now.

I'll leave it up to you for business logic on when to really trigger that, or maybe if you leave the activity it's okay to reload that content.  Best of luck.